# Which User Control event comes between data binding (other controls) and Render?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater, user-controls

I'm currently building a user control that displays a message when a Repeater is empty.

The idea is simple, provide the user control with the ID of the Repeater. When the user control is rendered look up the Repeater and check `Items.Count`. If it's zero then display the message.

I would like to add one more feature though. I want to be able to **hide** the Repeater if there are no Items.

Obviously I can't do this in `protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)` because the Repeater has (possibly) already been rendered. I also can't do this when the the Repeater ID is assigned to the user control, as the databinding hasn't happened yet.

So my question is.. what event can I override in my user control where **databinding has occurred**, but **rendering has not**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Page's PreRender event.  That way binding has happened but nothing has yet been rendered although they are just about to.

Comment: Oh.. actually I think I know what you mean. I can add a `protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)` signature to my User Control. I will try that.